# No module named 'processing.core.AlgorithmProvider' in QGIS3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am working on QGIS plugin bufferbypercentage.

```
# Import the PyQt and QGIS libraries  
from PyQt5.QtCore import *  
from PyQt5.QtGui import *  
from qgis.core import *  

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py  
from . import resources_rc  # lint:ok  

# Import the code for the dialog  
from .bufferbypercentagedialog import BufferByPercentageDialog  

# Import the Processing libraries so we can add the algorithm to the Processing menu
from processing.core.Processing import Processing  
from processing.core.GeoAlgorithm import GeoAlgorithm  
from processing.core.parameters import ParameterVector  
from processing.core.parameters import ParameterNumber  
from processing.core.parameters import ParameterTableField  
from processing.core.outputs import OutputVector  
from processing.tools import dataobjects, vector  
from processing.core.AlgorithmProvider import AlgorithmProvider
```

This gives me error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\PROGRA~1\SURVEY~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in
>   runcode
>       exec(code, self.locals)   File "", line 1, in    File "C:/PROGRA~1/SURVEY~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line
>   666, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'processing.core.AlgorithmProvider'

I am testing it on qgis master 2.99

Is AlgorithmProvider removed? If yes then what is have to use.

Comment: [AlgorithmProvider was removed](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/5614df4b6e94c49449f7cc6374578f481f280769/doc/api_break.dox#L2599) ,use the [QgsProcessingProvider class](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingProvider.html)

Comment: And plugins built on qgis master 2.99 using the most recent Plugin Builder 3 plugin fail with this error, pffft

Comment: @FranRaga Please post your comment as an answer so this thread can be marked as answered

Answer (score 4):

based on my comment

[AlgorithmProvider was removed](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/5614df4b6e94c49449f7cc6374578f481f280769/doc/api_break.dox#L2599) ,use the [QgsProcessingProvider class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingProvider.html)